# What response to send when receiving a Zapier webhook

Tags: webhooks, zapier

I'm implementing a Mail to Webhook Zapier integration. When testing the webhook during the creation process, the test is stuck and won't move on to the next step in the creation process.
When looking at my app logs, I see that the webhook is being sent over and over again, and doesn't stop, even though the app sends '200 ok' in the response.
Why does this happen? What response do I need to send to make it finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

It's hard to say for sure, but I believe the response needs to include some content. At minimum, that's `{}` (valid JSON), but it could also be `{"ok": true}` or something.

That said, an empty response is something we should handle so if you could write into `partners@zapier.com` with your zap id, we can take a closer look!

Comment: Update: the webhook was working ok when deployed, with any '200 ok' response. The problem was with the test that for some reason was not stopping and sending endless test webhooks. So I guess it's ok for me now.